# R cumulative distinct count customer and products

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataset of sold skus with customer id.

```
dtSales = data.table(sku = c("a", "b", "b", "c", "b","b", "c", "d", "b", "a"),
                 qty = c(1,1,1,2,1,3,2,1,4,2),
                 customer = c(1,1,2,2,3,1,1,1,4,1))

    id sku qty customer
1:  1   a   1        1
2:  2   b   1        1
3:  3   b   1        2
4:  4   c   2        2
5:  5   b   1        3
6:  6   b   3        1
7:  7   c   2        1
8:  8   d   1        1
9:  9   b   4        4
10: 10   a   2        1
```

I can find how many times each sku was bought and how many customers bought each product.

```
dtSales[,.(ttlqty=sum(qty), distinctCustomer= length(unique(customer))) ,by=sku][order(-ttlqty)]

    sku ttlqty distinctCustomer
1:   b     10                4
2:   c      4                2
3:   a      3                1
4:   d      1                1
```

I would like to have a cumulative count for the customers. 
First row: how many different customers bought product 1
Second row: how many different customers bought product 1 or product 2
...

Thanks

Comment: Check out `cumsum` and apply it to your distinctCustomer column and you should have the desired output?.

Comment: I don't simply want to add up the distinctCustomer column, I want to find distinct customers who bought any of the previous products. So if customer 1 bought product b and c I want to count him only once.

Comment: For someone to help you right, I believe you should update your question with specifics and also the desired output based on the input you posted above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds as if you want a cumulative union of customers. Cumulative operations can be performed by `Reduce` with `accumulate=TRUE`

```
(cu<-Reduce(function(x,y) union(x,y),
   Map(unique,split(df$customer,df$sku)), acc=TRUE))
```

Produces, in the same order as `levels(df$sku)`, the cumulative union of customers who bought product `a`, product `a` or `b`, etc.

```
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

[[4]]
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Finally, we can get the length of each and place alongside the levels

```
data.frame(sku=levels(df$sku),cc=sapply(cu,length))
```

```
sku cc
1   a  1
2   b  4
3   c  4
4   d  4
```

Note that I have used `data.frame`s and base functions throughout.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to A. Webb. for pointing to Reduce. I wanted to have the results sorted from the most sold products to less sold, so I adapted.

Final solution

```
library(data.table)


dtSales = data.table(sku = c("a", "b", "b", "c", "b","b", "c", "d", "c", "a"),
                     qty = c(1,1,1,2,1,3,2,1,4,2),
                     customer = c(1,1,2,2,3,1,1,1,4,1))

#convert sku column to factor
dtSales$sku <- as.factor(dtSales$sku)

#find how many times each sku was bought and sort from high to low
orderedSku = dtSales[,.(ttlqty=sum(qty), distinctCustomer= length(unique(customer))) ,by=sku][order(-ttlqty)]

#order the sku from most sold to less sold
dtSales$sku <- factor(dtSales$sku, levels= orderedSku$sku)

#cumulative distinct count of customers
cu<-Reduce(function(x,y) union(x,y), Map(unique,split(dtSales$customer, dtSales$sku)), acc=TRUE)

#merge the results
data.frame(sku=levels(dtSales$sku), qty=orderedSku$ttlqty, cc=sapply(cu,length))
```